# Вызов метода класса перед его определением

Tags: python, django

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
image   = models.ImageField(upload_to=getUploadPath, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Изображение')

def getUploadPath(instance, filename):
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
    dir = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "upload", self.__class__.__name__)
    if not os.path.isdir(dir): os.makedirs(dir)
    return os.path.join(dir, "%s%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext))

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title
```

Суть такова: от этого класса наследуются другие. Необходимо, чтобы при аплоаде картинки она перемещалась в папку с названием модуля.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):   
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=lambda s, f: TestModel.getUploadPath(s, f),\
                              blank=True, verbose_name=u'Изображение')

    def getUploadPath(self, filename):
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
        dir = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "upload", self.__class__.__name__)
        if not os.path.isdir(dir):
            os.makedirs(dir)
        return os.path.join(dir, "%s%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    def getUploadPath(self, filename):
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
        dir = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "upload", self.__class__.__name__)
        if not os.path.isdir(dir):
            os.makedirs(dir)
        return os.path.join(dir, "%s%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext))

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=getUploadPath, blank=True,\
                                verbose_name=u'Изображение')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

Comment: Спасибо, но ну так не интересно :)
Я сейчас вообще вынес функцию в глобальную область видимости — так даже удобнее.
Но хотелось бы иметь на руках возможность вызвать функцию в независимости от порядка ее определения

Comment: Если нужно именно имя модуля, а не класса, то self.__class__.__module__
Функцию можно вынести из класса, создав ее перед объявлением класса.

Comment: Что значит независимо от порядка определения?